# Delete old articles or perform redirect to the new one covering the same topic?

Tags: duplicate-content, keywords

In my site, I had noticed that I have 2 old articles for the same topic but diffrent content as below:

- Data Migration Part 1
- Data Migration part 2

Now I have a new article that already published with `Data Migration` but also has different content!

**Now what should I do?**

- Redirect the 2 old articles to the new one.
- Set the Canonical URL for the old articles to the new article.
- Delete 2 old articles
- Leave the 3 articles (Is it considered duplicate content or keyword cannibalization?)

Comment: Would users benefit from reading both articles or do they cover all the same things about the topic?

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller for your usual support, actually it covers the same in a different way and structure! article one has information directly as a short post but the new one includes some info from the old one and more details about the topic itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the two older articles, update both of them with references to the new article (e.g. add an editor's note with a link to the new article to each), make sure that the modified dates for the old articles' URLs on the site's XML sitemap reflect the update, and leave the canonical tags as self-referencing. I suggest this other method because 301 redirects work best to pass "SEO juice" (sort of a unreal concept to begin with but whatever) when the previous content at the start URL is near identical to the new content at the target URL. Since you said that only the topic is the same between all three and that the new one is published already, it would be better to simply work with interlinks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, to be honest, I have confused now, what is the best option in such cases, redirects or canonical :)

Comment: Redirects are for when you "separate" a webpage/ content from the URL it used to have and move it to a new URL. The redirect both preserves all continuous inbound traffic to the page/ content and passes all of the SEO benefits the old URL has "gained". A canonical tag is primarily for when different versions - identical copies, portions, or very similar drafts - of the same content exist at different URLs on the same or a different domain as the canonical indicates the original or most authoritative version. Both work on the level of pieces of content, not on the level of topics or entities.